# Exclude multiple values using <>

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a query that returns results excluding 4 specific values from a columns.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT CustomerID,
       ContactName,
       Country
FROM   Customers
WHERE  CustomerID IN (SELECT CustomerID
                      FROM   Customers
                      WHERE  (Country <> ('UK')('Australia')('Canada')));
```

This works if I exclude only one country but not multiple.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

Use `NOT IN` operator

The list should be separated by *comma* no need to have open/close parenthesis for each value inside the list. Also you don't need `sub-query` just add the filter `Where` clause

```
SELECT CustomerID,
       ContactName,
       Country
FROM   Customers
WHERE  Country NOT IN ( 'USA', 'UK', 'Australia', 'Canada' )
```

Make sure you dont pass any `NULL` values inside the list because `NOT IN` fails when there is a `NULL` value present in the list

Answer (score 1):

```
Select
  CustomerID, ContactName, Country 
From Customers
Where CustomerID NOT IN ('USA','UK','Australia','Canada');
```

Answer (score 1):

You may consider defining excluded countries in a special table (e.g. ExcludedCountry). This will separate your data (excluded countries) from your logic (select customer not in excluded countries). In this case, your query can look like:

```
select CustomerID, ContactName, Country 
from Customers C
    left join ExcludedCountry EC ON EC.Name = C.CustomerID 
where CustomerID IS NOT NULL
```

or

```
-- may be faster than above
select CustomerID, ContactName, Country 
from Customers C
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from ExcludedCountry EC 
    where EC.Name = C.CustomerID)
```

The advantage of this solution is an easier management of your excluded items.

Comment: 1+ for the second suggested way... the first one usually performs worse. [Reference](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join).

Comment: Yes, that's I put the comment that the second query may be faster. It may also depend on number of items to actually see a difference.